# Changing textbox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, textbox

I am trying to change textbox data on my program, but it isn't working.
The form is already shown but when I try it doesn't update.
I'm trying to use form1.show(); but my program is using multithreading and it spams windows in every thread.

What I tried so far is this.

Form1.CS code

```
  private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText);
    public void UpdateTextBox(string input)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            paidbox.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input });
        }
        else
        {
            paidbox.Text = paidbox.Text + input;

                // textBox.Text = textBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + input // This might work as append in next line but haven't tested so not sure
        }
    }
```

On my Program.CS I used on every bool I want it to be updated.

```
        public static Form1 MainLogWindow = new Form1();
                Cheker.MainLogWindow.UpdateTextBox("test test");
```

This isn't working, it compiles successfully but it doesn't update when the process start the text on textbox.

Sorry for my bad english.

P.S I'm new on C#, I know only php and javascript so this is so new to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877431/changing-text-box-from-another-class

Comment: @TheGeneral Field 'Cheker.MyForm' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null