# Ho do I edit Textbox of Form1 through another class in c#

Tags: c#, class

I have Form1.Designer.cs and another class MyClass. MyClass.cs simply contains methods for API actions. In MyClass.cs, using the API I try to get the number of devices connected to my PC and store it in the list. Now I want to display that list in the ComboTexbox in Form1.Designer.cs

When I write the method in Form1.cs of course it works perfectly fine.
Code in Form1.cs

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass.Connect();
            MyClass.GetConnted_Device();
         }
```

code in MyClass

```
public string[] DriverNameList;
public List<string> DeviceNameList = new List<string>();
public int device_length = 0;

public void GetConnted_Device()
        {   
            " ommitted code to get the connected device using API"
            // Get all the device and stored them in DriverNamelist 

            DeviceNameList = DriverNameList.ToList();
            device_length = DeviceNameList.Count;
          }
```

I tried the following method but it seems I have to create a separate method for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877500/19059210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The only object that should be making changes to a form is that form. The methods in that class should return data. The form can then call a method, get the data and update its own control(s) with that data. Alternatively, the method could remain `void` and then the form could call the method and then get the data from the appropriate field of that class. Either way, it's the form getting the data from the class instance and then updating its own UI. That other class should not have to know anything about what's using it.

By the way, public members should be properties, not fields.

Comment: Thank you so much but I really appreciate if you could clarify with an example for the second part

_"Alternatively, the method could remain void and then the form could call the method and then get the data from the appropriate field of that class."_

Comment: @Lha, what second part? Are you talking about using properties instead of fields? If so, what do you not understand about the countless examples already on the web?

Comment: Thank you @John, For the time being, I will use the Return value, being a newbie and jumping right into the project really messes with my basic concept.

Comment: Whether to return a value or set a property would depend on how you intend to use the data. If it's only going to be used once then a return value is more appropriate. If you want to be able to access the data again without calling the method again then a property would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

DeviceNameList.ForEach(x => comboBoxTextBox.Items.Add(x));

Comment: You should be using one call to `AddRange` rather than multiple calls to `Add`. Also, I doubt that the actual adding of items is the problem here, but how the other object gets access to the control.

Comment: I have used the above suggestion for the Return value
`
List<string> Devices = MyClass.GetConnted_Device();
Devices.ForEach(item => cmB_Device.Items.Add(item));
`
Its working with no major errors.

Comment: @Lha, as I mentioned, you should use a single call to `AddRange` to add all the items in a batch. If they will be the only items, you might even set the `DataSource` property instead. Adding items individually would certainly work but should be the last option.